# Get selected code image in visual studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

How get image of selected code in Visual Studio editor using code implementation? 
It is possible?
Forgive me my bad englis.

Comment: Hit the print screen button and paste it into ms paint.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to do it Visual Studio itself. If you are using Windows Vista and up you can use the [Snipping tool](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Use-Snipping-Tool-to-capture-screen-shots) which is extremely easy and quick to use.

If you are on an older OS then you probably need to resolve in a different third party application to handle the screenshot taking for you, or just make use of the print screen button on your keyboard.